# Creating a java string randomizer from an array Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to create a password generator (random string generator) that will eventually send to a database but when I use the below code in an activity the app terminates with the error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=67; index=85" this code should return a random value from a character array using a loop to generate the string.

```
package com.example.zakratcliffe.androidantitheft;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private TextView textViewUsername, textViewUserEmail;
private EditText textEditDescription, textEditPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    if (!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }

    textViewUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
    textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUseremail);
    textEditDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
    textEditPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    textViewUserEmail.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail());
    textViewUsername.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUsername());

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String pass = Generated_pass();
            textEditPassword.setText(pass);
        }
    });
}

String Generated_pass(){
    char[] GenPass = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '@', '!', '?', '&', '%', '~'};
    int i = 1;
    String GeneratedPass = "";
    while (i < 13){
        Random r = new Random();
        int Character = r.nextInt(66 - 0) + 66;
        System.out.println(GenPass[Character]);
        GeneratedPass = GeneratedPass + GenPass[Character];
        i++;
    }
    return  GeneratedPass;
}
public void SendToDB(View v){
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuLogout:
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).logout();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: just update this line: `int Character = r.nextInt(GenPass.length);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do

int Character = r.nextInt(66);

instead of

int Character = r.nextInt(66 - 0) + 66;

as "r.nextInt(66-0) + 66" may generate any random number between 0 to 66, and then to that number 66 is added, thus the character has value more than 66, which is inaccessible in the array(has length 66), and hence the exception arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Or to make the code robust, instead of hardcoding 66, use:

```
    while (i < 13){
        Random r = new Random();
        int Character = r.nextInt(GenPass.length);
        System.out.println(GenPass[Character]);
        GeneratedPass = GeneratedPass + GenPass[Character];
        i++;
    }
    return  GeneratedPass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String Generated_pass(){
    char[] GenPass = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
                      'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                      'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4',
                      '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
                      'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
                      'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y',
                      'Z', '@', '!', '?', '&', '%', '~'};
    int i = 1;
    String GeneratedPass = "";
    int min = 0;
    int max = 54;
    while (i < 13){
        Random r = new Random();
        int Character =r.nextInt(max - min + i) + min;
        System.out.println(GenPass[Character]);
        GeneratedPass = GeneratedPass + GenPass[Character];
        i++;
    }
    return  GeneratedPass;
}
```

Try this feature